# Where can I find people to collaborate on software projects?

Tags: resources, collaboration

I mean not on open source, but software to build and sell.

They don't have to be programmers, they can be also people who have ideas or with a marketing background.

Is there any good internet platform for this?

Comment: Best place I found was https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingBuddies/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Professional social network LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/) is a good place to start out with. You can get involved in groups with same interests and find people to start out a project, find employers and so on.

Comment: Seems stupid, as you have your current working network also on that platform, meaning stupid questions from colleagues as well as your boss.

Answer (score 2):

Try [FairSoftware](http://www.fairsoftware.net/home) or more specifically [FairSoftware/TeamUp](http://www.fairsoftware.net/teamup).

Comment: Seems to be only for "startups", not for other projects.

Answer (score 2):

[builditwith.me](http://builditwith.me)

[bettercodes.org](http://bettercodes.org)

Comment: Both links dead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [WhyNot? idea exchange](http://www.whynot.net/). It is a general idea exchange forum. Some of the ideas are software related.

Comment: WhyNot dead. (3 more characters left, thanks SO)

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens. For a start, look at the 37signals [Gig Board](http://gigs.37signals.com/) and [RentACoder](http://www.rentacoder.com/RentACoder/DotNet/default.aspx).

Comment: He asked for participants not employees.

Answer (score 0):

[Craigslist](http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites)'s gigs section has requests for this from time to time.  Caveat emptor, of course.

Answer (score -2):

collabfinder or behance.....  i would use those to start a project and meet people interested.

funding of course kickstarter...

your own web page to promote projects and accept applications or to have a nondisclosure agreement...  for instance my rough draft on my site  http://www.pajamajunctionproduction.com/?page_id=23  i also set the nondisclosure on the register page...  it is to protect projects...

collaboration software...  there is tons of it...  i won't even bother to list these...  but i do enjoy pirate pad for anything writing related...  team speak channel's or skype are extremely useful as well...

I rarely meet people interested in projects on any particular site for it...  i have but rarely do they wish to stick around....  a lot of people will come and go trying to pilfer idea's or being nosy...  generally the most helpful people are met just playing games on the internet...  can't even express how many developers, programmers and artists play video games online...  it seems to be the best place to find bored people looking for real projects...

best advice i can give from my experience...